# Android Gridview getting focus

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, focus

I have a Linear Layout and at the very bottom i have a gridview (hotelsGrid) that i populate with more items to see, the problem is that after i set my adapter the view on the screen jumps to the bottom to show the gridview and i need to stay on the top, how can i archieve this?

Here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/hotel_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ActivityHotelDetail">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/panel_with_border_nopadding"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hotelName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/fondo_titulo"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
                    android:text="Nombre del Hotel"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="28sp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/hotelMainImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:paddingRight="1dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/fondo_360"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/video360"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                        <com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.video.VrVideoView
                            android:id="@+id/video_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="250dip"
                            android:scrollbars="@null"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/playButton"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/playbutton"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
                    </FrameLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/play_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:paddingStart="0dp"
                            android:paddingTop="4dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/play_on"/>
                        <!-- Seeking UI & progress indicator.-->
                        <SeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="32dp"
                            android:layout_weight="8"/>

                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/volume_toggle"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:paddingStart="0dp"
                            android:paddingTop="4dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/volume_on"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hotelDistance"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="26sp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/fondo_distancia"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="distance"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hotelAddress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imagepreview"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Direccion"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorSecundary"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hotelDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:text="Descripcion"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/otherHotelsRL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/panel_with_border_nopadding"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/otherViewsTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Fotos"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorSecundary"
                    android:textSize="22sp"/>

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/otherViewsTxt"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:fillViewport="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/thumb1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@mipmap/icon_360"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/thumb2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/thumb1"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@mipmap/icon_360"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/thumb3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/thumb2"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@mipmap/icon_360"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:alpha="0.8"
                    android:background="#222222"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_white_24dp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:alpha="0.8"
                    android:background="#222222"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_white_24dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/otherHotelsTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/panel_with_border_padding"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Mas Hoteles Interesantes"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColorSecundary"
                    android:textSize="22sp"/>

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/hotelsGrid"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="350dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="15dp"
                    android:numColumns="2"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:verticalSpacing="15dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add focusable:true and focusableintouch:true to top layout. and also put <REQUEST> tag

Comment: nope.. it didnt worked

Comment: private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        }
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your top level Layout View --Linearlayout. to make it `focusable`

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/top_layout" 
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
```

Now in Activity:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.top_layout);
layout.requestFocus();
```

Then call `layout.requestFocus();` after you have set the Adapter